# Is it Possible to View Netflix Instant Movies on Ubuntu?

Tags: boxee, moonlight, netflix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to stream Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix)

I've tried Boxxe and Moonlight but nothing works.