# Is there an equivalent of Silverlight?

Tags: software-recommendation, moonlight, pipelight

I need Silverlight installed on my Ubuntu system, so that I can see some of the Microsoft websites(mainly videos).

Are there any alternatives to Silverlight in Ubuntu? If so, what are they and how do I install them?

Comment: There is a workaround to use Silverlight by using a custom version of `wine`, follow the instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/a/219068/15943

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Moonlight is an open source Silverlight implementation written in Mono. You can download it here: http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/

Comment: Haha you've got to be quick on these things! Jorge has ninja'd me a couple of times.

Comment: Unfortunately Moonlight is now in status - Discontinued. :/

Answer (score 4):

pipelight released and we can use it for silverlight as a best alternative moonlight.

to install that open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mqchael/pipelight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight
```

Answer (score 4):

Pipelight is the best alternative to Silverlight plugin in Ubuntu. Just open the terminal and add the following repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight
```

There is no need to do anything else. The installed plugin should appear among addons in your Internet browser and you should enjoy watching silverlight videos :) I have tested it in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

There is Moonlight that is a project from Novell.

Moonlight is available in different forms:

- packages in the official repository ( but tipically outdated )
- plugin for Firefox ( .xpi ) http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/
- source code from git as described in this page
  http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight

Answer (score 1):

After you install pipelight, you also need to run two commmands with Ubuntu 14.04, as per [this IT World page](http://www.itworld.com/software/414056/install-silverlight-alternative-pipelight-ubuntu-1404).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

I have tested this with Amazon instant video and it works!