# How to install Microsoft Silverlight plugin?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, microsoft, moonlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent of Silverlight?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34805/is-there-an-equivalent-of-silverlight)

When I install it normally it says itś not compatible with Firefox 7..
How to fix this I need silverlight plugin for certain things?