# Silverlight in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mono, moonlight

I want to enable Silverlight on Ubuntu 14.04. I have seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34805/is-there-an-equivalent-of-silverlight) that provides a [link to moonlight](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/). However, the latest version of moonlight, seem to support only [Mac, Windows and OpenSuse](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html), while the [previous version](http://mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Ubuntu) does not support Ubuntu 14.04. How is it possible for users of Ubuntu 14.04 to use an application similar with Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install `wine-compholio` from a PPA called `ppa:pipelight/stable`. Basically, it runs Silverlight in a Wine environment. See here: http://www.compholio.com/wine-compholio. Install the package with your browser closed. When you reopen it, you should be able to use Silverlight sites.
 For Netflix and a couple of other sites you will also need to adjust the user agent your browser sends out.

Comment: It didn't work for me. (Ubuntustudio 14.04 64bit)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably chase down piplight to try to use silverlight in Ubuntu - I think the moonlight project for Ubuntu was abandoned.  You can peruse the [forums for mono](http://go-mono.com/forums/) for information about moonlight and linux / Ubuntu, and the [launchpad project](https://launchpad.net/pipelight) for information about pipelight.