# original silverlight in ubuntu? (moonlight not accepted from italian website)

Tags: moonlight

I know about moonlight but  it doesn't work on an italian web site I need:
http://www.video.mediaset.it/video/motogp/full/258461/motogp-di-valencia.html.

I'm running chromium browser on ubuntu 11.10, Novell Moonlight - Version: 3.99.0.3.

I cannot see a way to solve this problem other that reboot on windows 7, if anybody can help.

I wonder if there's a way to install the original microsoft silverlight on linux.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a workaround to use Silverlight by using a custom version of `wine`, follow the instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/a/219068/15943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moonlight at the current time is *the* Silverlight client for Linux; there are no alternatives that I am aware of, and Microsoft does not have an official Silverlight client for Linux.

Moonlight should in general be compatible with Silverlight, except in cases where the Silverlight application in question [uses Microsoft PlayReady DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_%28runtime%29#DRM). It is possible the website you are trying to use is protected by this DRM scheme.

Comment: I understand. It's just sad that cause of this I have to remove ubuntu to friends of mine and install windows xp. I tried to go through wine but the browser didn't work good, finally tried with a virtual machine but the pc is too old and the video is resulting slow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight unfortunately doesn't work on Ubuntu, it's Windows-specific.

Comment: I guess only in Italy the public television websites force users to use microsoft windows :(

Comment: In Poland to watch sport (by official website - HD for free ) it's the same :/