# Netflix on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, video, moonlight, netflix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to stream Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix)

Has anybody found a workaround to watch `Netflix` on Ubuntu other than running Windows XP through VirtualBox?  At this point my girlfriends fascination with Netflix is the only reason I still use windows for anything.

Netflix now supports Chrome OS 13 or higher, and Mac OS 10.4.11 or later.  I have tried [Moonlight](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/) without success.

Comment: No... sign the petition! http://www.petitiononline.com/Linflix/petition.html

Answer (score 2):

There were [rumors last July](http://benjaminkerensa.com/2011/07/30/netflix-instant-is-coming-to-the-entire-linux-community/) of an official Netflix client for Linux within the next 12 months, but I've heard little since then.

Moonlight will probably never be an option, as there are [no plans to license the Playready DRM](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/native-netflix-client-coming-linux-in-12-months/), which is used by Netflix.

The Netflix plugin for Chrome (including Chrome OS) provided a glimmer of hope, but for [various technical reasons](http://www.ehomeupgrade.com/2011/08/12/netflixs-chrome-os-plugin-may-be-one-of-googles-first-native-client-examples/), this hasn't yet made Netflix available in Chrome for Linux.

So while the signs are increasingly positive, I wouldn't hold your breath until we hear an official, on-the-record release date (or at least a time-frame) from Netflix.  In the meantime, it seems your only option is to continue to run Windows in Virtualbox (and, for bonus points, [sign the petition](http://www.petitiononline.com/Linflix/petition.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Netflix has no plans of supporting linux. They use DRM infested Microsoft Silverlight that also has no plans to support linux. Moonlight doesn't support this drm. There is [a petition](http://www.petitiononline.com/Linflix/petition.html) floating around somewhere that you can add your name to and perhaps you should email Netflix directly and let them know how you feel.