# Need Net flix Plugin so i can stream video with ubuntu 11.10 from NF account

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to stream Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix)

Is there a plug in that will replace silverlight so I can stream Netflix? 
THx-rn

Ubuntu 11.10
Pentium(R)4 
4 CPU 3.40GHz x2
32 bit

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box plugin for Linux that allows for Silverlight to work in Ubuntu.

Silverlight is Microsoft's proprietary web plugin program.  They don't have an open source equivalent, or an equivalent in Ubuntu or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source alternative to Silverlight called Moonlight, but it does not provide DRM protection at all. That is owned by Microsoft and can not be disassembled for use on a Linux machine.

http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight