# Can I connect a media player to Ubuntu

Tags: hardware, netflix

I want to switch 100% to Ubuntu from Windows. Of course I must have my Netflix account which I know won't work with Linux natively. My question is, can I connect a Roku box or another media player box to Ubuntu so that I can watch Netflix through Linux?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you'd want to do something like that. A Roku player just needs a screen and an internet connection to play Netflix content. Why would you want to connect it to an Ubuntu machine???

Comment: Because I live in a 36FT RV and use my computer for my TV. Netflix obviously isn't compatible with Linux so if I could plug a Roku box into my computer or by a card to do so then I'd be able to completely do away with Windows and use Ubuntu only and be able to watch Netflix using it. I want Netflix running through the OS, not straight to the monitor.

Comment: Hm..., you may need something like this: http://www.belkin.com/uk/switch2/. It's not quite what you suggested, but perhaps someone else can provide a more appropriate solution.

Comment: That's a really good idea using a switch :) That's definitely an idea that would work good. The Roku box has HDMI out so I would have to get an adapter cable for the switch or of-course buy one with HDMI. I like that idea and will be reading and learning more about switches now. A switch and a Roku box or equivalent would be a perfect fix for linux users to stream netflix without the need of windows or a virtual machine. I'm very computer savvy but have never used a switch. Thanks for that suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Feeding a video stream from a Roku box into your computer would violate the DMCA and prolly get you sued by the RIAA. That's the bad news. The good news is you can run netflix in a modified wine environment. Check out [How can I use Netflix on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix)

You could also get one of the newer monitors that accept multiple inputs and connect the Roku box to that.