# How can I watch Netflix or LoveFilm .com on Ubuntu

Tags: netflix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to stream Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix)

I have installed moonlight in me Firefox but netflix still dont work what is the solution t this please as i love watching movies.