# Netflix DRM error (Ubuntu 12.10, VirtualBox, Win7)

Tags: 12.10, netflix, drm

Has anyone seen the Netflix DRM error described below? If so, is there a way around it?

To attempt to solve the problem of viewing Netflix on Ubuntu, I have created a virtual machine running Windows 7. This approach has been suggested in the answers to [Is there a way to stream Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix) and can be seen working in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuyPJFhVTxQ).

I am running Ubuntu 12.10, VirtualBox 14.1.18, Windows 7, and Firefox 16.0.2. I am able to login to Netflix, select a show to watch, and see the show start to load, but then I get the following error.

[image]

## Solution

The solution is on the [link](http://eikon.morogen.com/2011/07/how-to-fix-netflix-drm-error-n8156-6003.html) provided by [bford16](https://askubuntu.com/users/106547/bford16).

Remove/rename the `mspr.hds` file.

Windows 7 location:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\PlayReady\mspr.hds
```

Windows XP location:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\PlayReady\mspr.hds
```

Comment: @fossfreedom, I just reviewed the FAQ to try to understand why you voted to close my question. Based on my understanding of the FAQ, my question is on topic. How would you suggest I modify the question to make it on topic, or on which stack exchange site should I post this question?

Comment: This is off-topic as per Meta (http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2425/wheres-the-off-topic-line) - i.e. this is an issue with Windows running within Virtualbox - this is not related to Ubuntu since ubuntu is just the host - its the windows guest at issue.  This would be more suited to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this error myself.  I plan to try the fix in this link:

http://eikon.morogen.com/2011/07/how-to-fix-netflix-drm-error-n8156-6003.html