# How do I watch netflix on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, netflix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to stream Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix)

I've tried running Netflix in firefox and chrome but it says I need windows or mac osx.  Is there any way to work around this?