# Problem with netflix-desktop and Kubuntu 12.10

Tags: kubuntu, netflix

Not quite sure if this is an appropriate place to ask the question as it isn't technically supported but I am having some issues with the netflix-desktop package on my Kubuntu 12.10 laptop.

Following the instructions listed here I added the ppa and then installed netflix-desktop and did not seem to get any errors during the installation.  However when I run netflix-desktop nothing seems to happen. (I know the poster here: [How can I use Netflix on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix) he had other things that were installed upon first launch but i didn't see anything else get configured)

I am wondering if there is something going wrong with the fact that I'm using Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt that would be a problem. It's possible that the PPA maintainer failed to include as dependencies some programs installed by default in Unity Ubuntu but not Kubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There are some windows dependencies that get installed on the first boot of netflix-desktop that don't always succeed. This happened to me once. So I typed *sudo apt-get -reinstall install netflix-desktop*    and it fixed it right up for me.  Also there is a point where Microsoft will want you to sign-off on a EULA. You'll need to tab to highlight the [OK} button.