# How do I get more up to date Silverlight/Moonlight?

Tags: firefox, browser, webapps, streaming, moonlight

For the german video streaming site SkyGo, I need Silverlight >= 4.06. I installed the most recent Moonlight plugin from http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx but this version is to old to work on that streaming site.
Is there a more recent (developer) version? If so, how can I install it?

Is there any other way to get nasty closed source DRM locked down streaming sites running?

Comment: Suggest look at this Q - should be able to play up-to-date silverlight stuff: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix

Comment: It looks like there are others keeping an eye on the netflix method as well.    https://answers.launchpad.net/netflix-desktop/+question/217365  It doesn't seem to work at the moment but could well be an eventual anwer.

Answer (score 3):

The Moonlight-project is dead for more than a year sadly. 
The famous plugin in Chrome-webbrowser seems to be also dead.

For Silverlight and using this awfull software it is better to run Windows in a Virtual Box and thus using this for your needs.

I know this isn't the answer you wanted to hear, but for using Silverlight it's better to run a Virtual Machine with Windows inside it.