# Pipelight stopped working in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pipelight

I think it happened after I updated my system yesterday. I cannot watch Netflix any more because it says I don't have Silverlight. Looking at chrome:plugins, there is no plugin for Silverlight. I tried disabling and re-enabling the plugin (sudo pipelight-plugin...). It was enabled without any error. Still the same. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/470594/65926

Comment: you can get native netfilx viewing with chrome with a bit of work: http://askubuntu.com/a/509947/47291

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has dropped support of NPAPI plugins and only supports PPAPI plugins. Since pipelight is (likely) a NPAPI plugin, it cannot be used in Chrome.

Comment: But I think it stopped working because Wine was updated. It was working perfectly until a few days ago! Did Chrome drop support for NPAPI plugins very recently?

Comment: Chrome 35 and Chromium 34 dropped support for NPAPI plugins.

Comment: And do you know when that was released? My previous version of Chrome was downloaded one week ago and worked well

Comment: Chrome 35 was released on May 20. You can go to About to see what version of Chrome you're running.

Answer (score 0):

I can use pipelight to access Netflix perfectly on my laptop. We should spoof the user agent to a browser running on either Windows/Mac since Netflix is not officially available for Linux. I recommend the following settings.

- Chrome: [User Agent Switcher Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) - Switch to Windows
  Firefox15
- Firefox: [User Agent Overrider](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-overrider/) - Switch to Windows Firefox26

Comment: I know that. That's why I said it wasn't working 'any more' :) But didn't know the extension for Firefox. Thanks