# updated chrome, now pipelight not working

Tags: 12.04, updates, google-chrome, pipelight

On my Pc that I only use to stream Amazon instant video. I have pipelight that up to now has been running fine
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, with Chrome as my browser and the user-agent switcher  set up for firefox 15/windows.
Today I did a software update and foolishly let Chrome update as well, not instant video is tell me to install Silverlight.
My question is, how to I sort this out so that pipelight does what it's meant to again and let me stream videos off of Amazon.

Comment: It's probably better to ask the Pipelight developers: https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight
Also, look though the previous questions there, maybe there is already an answer to your problem.

Comment: Have you tried reenabling it: `pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight` ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/470581/241580

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/470594/65926

Answer (score 4):

Latest Chrome has dropped support for the old plugin APIs (see http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html).

Therefore any plugins that use such an API will not work anymore on latest Chrome browser for Ubuntu. They will work however ok in Firefox.

It may take some time until developer can respond to that situation and create compatible plugins, if ever.