# Ace Stream P2p Multimedia Plug-in Missing in chrome://plugins

Tags: google-chrome, vlc, plugins

Ace Stream P2P Multimedia Plug-in Missing in chrome://plugins

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPJfv.png

I have installed sudo `apt-get install acestream-full`

I did everything like here: http://forum.torrentstream.org/index.php?topic=1933.0

PS: Mozilla works just fine...

Comment: Root causes are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470549/pipelight-stopped-working-in-google-chrome/470581#470581) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470594/how-do-i-get-java-plugin-working-on-google-chrome).