# cannot add repository ppa:pipelight/stable

Tags: repository

I'm trying to get NETFLIX setup on my computer, but when I type in the first command everyone says I need to do, this is what happens:

```
emile@ManCave:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable  
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:pipelight/stable'.  
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Any ideas on why that would be coming up?

Comment: before adding repository have you tried.  "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: ppa looks correct

Comment: Is it `ppa:pipelight/stable` or `ppa:mqchael/pipelight-daily`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to stream Netflix?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix)

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting is correct, it's the server that's having the problem. This is not the only PPA affected right now, as I just answered another question that is having the same problem: [Issue adding ppa's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483479/issue-adding-ppas/483488#483488)

I would suggest trying again later, or perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: Ok that's good to know. At least I know it's not something I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: Yes there is a problem in launchpad server now. Will be ok soon. try later.