# How can i fix the add-apt-repository hang?

Tags: apt, ppa, add-apt-repository

I'm not sure what happened, but add-apt-repository doesn't work anymore. If I try, it just hangs:

After

"[sudo] password for cyanogenhacker:"

and entering the password, it just flashes the cursor and does nothing for about thirty seconds. Afterwards it states

"Please check that the PPA name or format is correct."

despite having copied and pasted and verifying multiple times that the text is correct. It happens with every PPA I try (Docky, Numix, noobslab/themes)

Any help??

Comment: what is the full command (with ppa)you entered ( with add-apt-repository)

Comment: Are you using a proxy server to connect to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the server's side. Several Launchpad repos are currently being affected. I've seen a few other questions with people running into this problem: [Issue adding ppa's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483479/issue-adding-ppas) , and [cannot add repository ppa:pipelight/stable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483456/cannot-add-repository-ppapipelight-stable/483489#483489) . I would suggest trying again later, or tomorrow.