# Issue adding ppa's

Tags: 14.04, ppa, repository, add-apt-repository, tlp

When I run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
```

It hangs after it asks for my password for a long time then shows this

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:linrunner/tlp'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I know the format is correct, I don't know what is wrong. I am not behind a proxy or any other internet blocking firewalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried both:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update`

and

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update`

and I too get the error:

`Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:linrunner/tlp'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

I believe this is because the server is having connectivity issues as when I try to visit the launchpad page https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/tlp in Firefox I get an error too:

```
Please try again

Sorry, there was a problem connecting to the Launchpad server.

Try reloading this page in a minute or two. If the problem persists, let us know in the #launchpad IRC channel on freenode.

Thanks for your patience.
```

My suggestion would be to try again later, or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The launchpad server is down at the moment. Try again a little later.