# Unable to use Netflix - still asked to install silverlight. Firefox, pipelight, silverlight enabled, passed troubleshooting

Tags: firefox, netflix, pipelight

I have recently got hold of a new laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried to set up netflix using the pipelight package as I had done previously on my old laptop using Mint 14. Now however, despite having followed the installation and configuration [instructions given for Ubuntu](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html) and installing and configuring User Agent Overrider on Firefox.

However, I'm still confronted with a message telling me I need to install the `silverlight plugin` when I try to watch anything on Netflix.

I have also troubleshooted as described on their [FAQ](http://pipelight.net/cms/faqs/faq-most-common-problems.html) and everything seems fine. I've trawled the internet for solutions, but can't seem to work it out.

Does anyone please have any suggestions as to why this might be and how I might fix it?

Comment: Did you run `sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight`?

Comment: Did you also set your Firefox User Agent Overrider to "Windows/Firefox 29?...and restart Firefox?

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. Yeah, I did both of those things, I still get the incompatibility message when I switch Agent Overrider back to the Linux/Firefox29 setting, and the request to install silverlight when I use the Windows/Firefox29 setting. The only thing unsual about my installation was that I has accidentally selected not to install the ms core fonts, but I then installed those separately and the output of `pipelight-plugin --system-check` tells me the `Fonts` test is now passed, where it wasn't before. Do you guys have any other ideas? Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: it only worked here with netflix-desktop from [here](http://itsfoss.com/netflix-ubuntu-1404-desktop-app/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to stream Netflix?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same problem on an older system, and thought that Netflix had changed something, but it was fixed by following hal7df's suggestions to:

```
 sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Which downloaded the newest Silverlight, 5.1, and worked immediately. You might try double checking your install and rerunning those commands, just to be sure. I've also seen issues with the apt keys used for pipelight from time to time. Good luck!