# Netflix Desktop

Tags: system-installation

So I am trying install the Netflix desktop and it's telling me that "MS true type fonts are not properly installed, would you like to download and install them now".... when I go to install install ttf-mscorefonts-installer.. it then says " it appears that you still have not instllaled the MS true type fonts, you need to accept the license agreement and install these fonts for Netflix Desktop to work properly." I have restarted and same problem... When I go reinstall  tff-mscorefonts-installer i get the message " Data files for some packages could not be downloaded" what do I do?

Comment: Netflix Desktop is no longer the favored method to get Netflix on Linux (or so it seems to me) - try [Pipelight](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/pipelight-silverlight-alternative-for.html) - it runs the Silverlight plugin in Wine and acts as a native browser plugin (NOTE: this will not work in the latest versions of Chrome). See if that solves your  problem.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix/509947#509947