# Netflix error code M7357-1003

Tags: netflix

Netflix error code M7357-1003.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.  I have done all the updates, upgrades, and and can play YouTube, Handbrake ripped movies, but I can't play Netflix using Chrome Browser.

I however can play Netflix on CentOS 7.  I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

and then `sudo apt-get update`.

However, it still won't play Netflix movies?  How to manually update the NSS3 to make it work?  thoughts?

Comment: Netflix I think needs Silverlight, and only wants to work on windows clients. Reading [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/how-can-i-use-netflix-on-ubuntu) may help.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of Chrome?  Silverlight is not required if you do.

Comment: I want to stress to people who have not noticed: Netflix on linux requires Chrome browser, not Chromium browser! By the way, the posting above correctly says Chrome, but sometimes people think the two are the same.

Comment: Vassilis answer saved me.

Answer (score 6):

I found my own solution:

```
############################
# NETFLIX ERROR M7357-1003 #
############################
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install -y libnss3-1d:i386
sudo apt-get install -y libxss1:i386
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: You have a typo: missing / between /etc/apt and sources.list.d

Comment: Other than above typo it actually resolved the issue. The only additional thing you want to do is change user-agent as described here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/can-now-watch-netflix-linux-natively-heres-how/

Comment: this did not work, Feb,20,2015 Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks @Meow! This worked.. I am using Ubuntu 14.04, I first tried running Netflix on Chromium, but learnt later that it is not possible on Chromium.. you have to install Chrome.. I have 64 bit arch, so I just changed to `libnss3`, `libnss3-1d`, and `libnss3-nssdb`, then rest of your recipe worked immediately. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/555615/netflix-on-chromium and http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-14-04