# Netflix on chromium

Tags: chromium, 14.10, netflix, html5

After reading an article about Ubuntu's netflix support I decided to try running netflix through chromium but I got this error code: M7063-1913 I assumed that it was a problem with html5 but in the playback preferences it doesn't give me the option to use it.

Comment: it only works in "Chrome" https://www.google.com/chrome/

Comment: @Sir_Yoshi If you respond I can give you access to the "netflix desktop-app for ubuntu"  It uses wine and auto updates itself so that you can run netflix without any hitches...

Comment: that is the workaround that I have been using but it is slow and this time it didn't work for some reason

Answer (score 3):

Currently only Chrome indeed, that is because Google's Chrome is the only browser that uses Encrypted Media Extension on Linux. Chromium and Opera even though based on the same engine do not bundle the DRM tools needed by Netflix.

Is unsure when/if Opera or Chromium will open the doors to DRM. Mozilla said that they will not implement EME directly, instead will support it via 3rd party sand boxed stuff sometime in the future.

Comment: how do I get chrome instead of chromium?

Comment: @Sir_Yoshi Mateo already posted the link. It should be offered to you when using a Linux machine.

Comment: I installed chrome but the error persists

Comment: That error is due to an outdated version of libnss3, libnss3-1d and libnss3-nssdb and/or because you need Chrome beta (only beta and dev versions work XD) check this http://www.ivegotavirus.com/netflix-natively-ubuntu-linux

Comment: First try just by installing the dev or beta Chrome I use the dev one and din't had to manualy upgrade libraries or change useragent. There is a repo for dev Chrome, but i can't find it rite now. Once i get home i'll check it out if you havent figured it by then.