# Silverlight is enabled, yet can't watch Netflix?

Tags: 16.04, chromium, plugins, netflix, pipelight

My machine is 32 bit so can't use Chrome.
Netflix does not work on `chromium`.

So I installed silver-light using `pipelight`:

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: Doesn't Netflix use HTML5 now? I think you have to install the right codecs, like chromium-ffmpeg (IIRC).

Comment: Last I knew Netflix doesn't use silverlight.

Comment: @xangua website says install Microsoft silverlight plug-in.

Comment: You need Chrome. No Chrome, no Netflix (on Linux). This is because Chrome implements HTML5's DRM system. http://askubuntu.com/a/509947/29595 http://askubuntu.com/a/760234/29595