# Netflix error M7703-1003 with Chrome in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, google-chrome, netflix

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and google chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit). I could use Netflix just yesterday night and today I am having this error M7703-1003. Reloading the page would not help.

your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got same **error M7703-1003** with Netflix on Chrome and **Ubuntu 16.04**.
Problem have been solved like this:

1. close Chrome, and then **RESET** chrome profile (by doing a back-up of current profile):

   ```
   cd ~/.config/google-chrome/
   mv Default Default-bkp
   ```
2. restart Chrome: it is opening on new fresh profile.
3. inside Chrome, add the "netflix icon":

   3.1 go to [Netflix chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netflix/deceagebecbceejblnlcjooeohmmeldh)

   3.2 go to [chrome://apps](http://chrome://apps), right click on Netflix icon and select **Open as Window** and **Create Shortcut**
   [image]

   Now Netflix is back available in the Dash
   [image]

---

*Sources:
[Creation the fresh Chrome profile](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=209342)
and [Creation of the Netflix icon in the Dash](https://askubuntu.com/a/509947/32413).*

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.094, I don't see a `Default` folder

Answer (score 0):

Netflix error M7703-1003 after loading Linux Vera 21.1. I loaded the regular (stable) version of chrome. No Bueno.
I beat crap, reset crap. failed on AMPrime also. I erased Chrome and loaded the "Unstable"ChromeD  115.0.5773.4-1  version from the Software Manager. It now works like it used to. I recall I had the Beta version of chrome on the last lfc.
I'm too old for this downgrade crap. Windows 7 worked fine. Should have left it alone!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).