# How to watch Netflix in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, netflix

I tried watching Netflix in Ubuntu, but browsers are not supported. It asks for IE. Is there any solution?

Comment: There is a long list of answers at http://askubuntu.com/q/1488/15003. Have you tried any of that yet?

Comment: I've tried the solution with wine... no success... :-(

Comment: Try the others then or open a new question and describe the issues with that method as detailed as possible.

Comment: Now days Netflix works fine with Firefox on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an answer. Go over to Google (https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) and download Google Chrome. Google Chrome is able to run Netflix "out of the box".

Comment: As long as you are on 64 bit, that its.

Comment: Ahh, good to know!

Comment: Now days Netflix works fine with Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: You can make it a desktop app via the menus "make shortcut" i think it's called