# how to run netflix on ubuntu 16.04 lts?

Tags: 16.04

how can I do tu use netflix whith ubuntu 16.04 LTS? I think that I need a complement but I don't know how to install it

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the below link which says, install chrome and that has netflix out of box.
[How to watch Netflix in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796818/how-to-watch-netflix-in-ubuntu)
let me know if you have question on installing chrome on ubuntu...

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. I have flagged the original question as a duplicate of the link to the link you posted which is also a duplicate. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. When you have more reputation you will be able to post comments too.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see Netflix in the default web browser that comes in all Ubuntu official flavors: Firefox.

When you login to your Netflix account you should see a popup inviting you to enable DRM to be able to play Netflix media.

You can also of course, as previous comments suggest, install Google Chrome (not the same as Chromium).

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/828286/now-that-i-have-firefox-49-how-do-i-watch-netflix